# how to handle useRouter()s async problem in nextJS

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, next-router

When I click the `Link` in `PublicMyTeam.js`
it passes query(=el.group_name) using router.

```js
// PublicMyTeam.js
<Link href={`/public/${el.group_name}`}>
    <a><h1 className={styles.team_name}>{el.group_name}</h1></a>
</Link>
```

But because of async problem of `useRouter()`, an error occured in `useEffect()` in `[group].js`.

It can't read `dbService.collection(group)`.

```js
// [group].js
const router = useRouter()
const { group } = router.query

async function getGroupPlayers() {
  const querySnapshot = await dbService.collection(group).doc('group_data').collection('players').get()
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const singlePlayerObject = {
      name: doc.data().name,
      photoURL: doc.data().photoURL,
      joined_date: doc.data().joined_date,
      rating: doc.data().rating,
      game_all: doc.data().game_all,
      game_win: doc.data().game_win,
      game_lose: doc.data().game_lose,
      status: doc.data().status,
      introduce: doc.data().introduce
    }
    setGroupPlayers(groupPlayers => [...groupPlayers, singlePlayerObject])
  })
  groupPlayers.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating)
}

useEffect(() => {
  getGroupPlayers()
}, [])
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `router` to the `useEffect`'s dependencies array, and check for `router.query.group` before calling `getGroupPlayers()`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.group) {
        getGroupPlayers()
    }
}, [router])
```

Comment: What if it is a Next.js(13) project where useEffect also restricted with "use client" ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try putting the contents of the entire async function inside of useEffect and make the function self-invoking

```
    useEffect(() => {
        (async function Update() {
            return (await page.current) === reviews_page
                ? true
                : set_reviews_page((page.current = reviews_page));
        })();
    }, [page.current, reviews_page]);
```

this works quite well for custom pagination I have configured with SWR. It's my workaround for the same problem

If you want to [read up on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), it's referred to as IIFEs (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

So, something like this should do the trick:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async function getGroupPlayers() {
  const querySnapshot = await dbService.collection(group).doc('group_data').collection('players').get()
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const singlePlayerObject = {
      name: doc.data().name,
      photoURL: doc.data().photoURL,
      joined_date: doc.data().joined_date,
      rating: doc.data().rating,
      game_all: doc.data().game_all,
      game_win: doc.data().game_win,
      game_lose: doc.data().game_lose,
      status: doc.data().status,
      introduce: doc.data().introduce
    }
    setGroupPlayers(groupPlayers => [...groupPlayers, singlePlayerObject])
  })
  groupPlayers.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating)
 })();
}, [])
```

Although, you may want to add some conditional logic for this to execute as intended (and a lifecycle dependency or two). make a useRef to reference group or groupPlayers and only trigger the lifecycle hook to execute on componentDidUpdate (similar to how I have the state updating when the page.current and reviews_page values differ). page.current is the useRef const for the reviews_page state as follows:

```
    const [reviews_page, set_reviews_page] = useState<number>(1);
    const page = useRef<number>(reviews_page);
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. :D
wow... it's pretty hard.
I'll try it later and then ask if I have new questions!